# Limiting the write access to Firestore DB outside app UI

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build an app that works like a classic videogame, with some challenges that the user must complete in order to advance. Based on how the user solves the puzzles, he/she will gain XP points, badges etc. The user can quit the app and come back later, with an authentication system.

I'm planning to use Firebase Auth for authentication and Firestore for the database. It's the first time I use Firebase services in (somewhat) production environments, but I've been experimenting a lot with their services lately.

Firestore will be used to store a set of data for every user, but mainly his/her score. I'm somehow familiar with Security Rules in Firestore, and know how to make sure that only authenticated users can write to the db, perform data validation before giving write permissions etc.

However, there's one problem I cannot come up with: how can I be sure that the (authenticated) user will not use the browser console, or a custom API call to update his/her points and write them to the DB? Like in the first part of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7PUm7LmAOw&t

To sum up: my expected result would be that the (authenticated) user could update his/her score on my Firestore DB only by using the UI (i.e. solving challenges) and not by making a direct call to the DB. I thought of some other solutions (e.g. sending only user response - like answers to a quiz - to the DB and then updating the scores server-side with Cloud Functions), but it seems to me that I'm over-complicating a simple issue.

I've watched and read a good amount of guides on security in Firestore: they do a good job explaining how to secure an app from un-authenticated hackers, but I am yet to find a guide on how to defend the app against unwanted behaviour from authenticated users.

Thank you in advance for any guidance on this, deeply appreciate it. Stay safe :)

UPDATE: looks like the only way to manage data flow to the DB when you can't "trust" the authenticated user is using Cloud Functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Listen to score, points, badges in real time using Firestore. You may set the security rules to these fields as READ ONLY for an authenticated user, setting write permission for a service user (that will be used in your cloud functions).
- Send Quiz answers using a cloud function, that will be processed using your service authenticated user (with write permissions to the collections).

Thus, your cloud function may be responsible for checking answers and preventing user abuse from console and other methods.

Comment: Thank you Tiago! So if I get this right you're suggesting to:

1) send the answers/choices to the DB
2) setup a Cloud Function to be triggered when the above data is written
3) use the CF to calculate the score and write it back to the DB

Am i getting this right?

Comment: Loopaka, you could use this approach of sending answers to DB and triggering a cloud function when the data changes, or, you could call a cloud function from your app (if you don't need to store the answer itself and just want to process it, storing and delivering scores, badges and results using Firestore). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable to know how to call a function from your app. Calling the cloud function from your app gives you the possibility of additional checks in server side before writing on the Firestore.

Comment: Callable functions looks like the way to go. Thanks!